# takeSnapshot() error of monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am testing monkeyrunner and using below .py file for screencapture.

screencapture image is generated but sometimes it occurs error in "resulet = device.takeSnapshot()"

I don't know what's the problem.
I have tested it with Eclipse. (Eclipse -> AVD , Skin WVGA854)

Please help me~ Thanks~

```
    # Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
    from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage

    # Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

    # Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
    # to see if the installation worked.
    #device.installPackage('D:\\study_java\\monkeyrunner\\HelloAndroid.apk')

    # sets a variable with the package's internal name
    package = 'com.example.helloandroid'

    # sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
    activity = 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid'

    # sets the name of the component to start
    runComponent = package + '/' + activity

    # Runs the component
    device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

    # Takes a screenshot
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(0.5)
    result = device.takeSnapshot()
    # Writes the screenshot to a file
    result.writeToFile('D:\\study_java\\monkeyrunner\\screen_shot.png','png')
```

Below is error log.

```
    D:\study_java\monkeyrunner>monkeyrunner d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.py

    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] Unab
    le to take snapshot
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]java.
    io.IOException: EOF
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:643)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:616)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AdbHelper.java:326)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.getScreenshot(Device.java:270)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice.takeSnapshot(AdbMonkeyDevice.jav
    a:197)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice.takeSnapshot(MonkeyDevice.java:83)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:381)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:385)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.py:37)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.p
    y)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:93)

    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:20
    3)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Scri
    pt terminated due to an exception
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Trace
    back (most recent call last):
      File "d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.py", line 27, in <module>
        result.writeToFile('D:\\study_java\\monkeyrunner\\screen_shot.png','png')
            at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyImage.writeToFile(MonkeyImage.java:85)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:46)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:43)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.Py.JavaError(Py.java:455)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.Py.JavaError(Py.java:448)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:177)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:414)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:418)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.py:37)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(d:\study_java\monkeyrunner\monkeytest.p
    y)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:93)

    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:20
    3)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Cause
    d by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyImage.writeToFile(MonkeyImage.java:85)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
    111019 16:47:17.000:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
    ... 16 more

    D:\study_java\monkeyrunner>
```

Comment: I have changed screen size of emul from WVGA854 to WVGA800. It's OK. Success rate of WVGA854 was about 50%. I don't know what should I do to take a snapshot normally on WVGA854. Thanks

Comment: Try giving the WVGA854 emulator a higher priority and perhaps its own core. (You can set this using task manager) That might help to improve your success rate.

Comment: I have the same problem. More information:
Doesn't happen with Android 4.0 and 4.0.3, does with 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3
Occurs with density  160 and 240 (others not tested)
No problem with 640*960, density 320, which would result in bigger snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

It has been so long since you asked this question but here is the answer anyway. Your code gives exception when you try to save the screen capture in the folder that you specified. If you change the following code:

```
result.writeToFile('D:\\study_java\\monkeyrunner\\screen_shot.png','png')
```

into:

```
result.writeToFile('D:/study_java/monkeyrunner/screen_shot.png','png')
```

Then you should be good to go! Please let me know if you encounter any other problems.